# Add simple event to each element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to add events dynamically to each element in my html, using data-* I get all elements and using `forEach` to iterate. But when I trigger events in any button, it returns in page the undefined value, it looks like it's lost the reference from this inside function, I really don't know what happened. Is the best approach to add events dynamically?

https://jsfiddle.net/tmmdsgoq/1/

```
<button data-event data-text="Button 1">Button 1</button>
<button data-event data-text="Button 2">Button 2</button>
<button data-event data-text="Button 3">Button 3</button>

<div id="container">

</div>

<script>
function init(){
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-event]");  
 elements.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML += this.text;
  });
 });
}

init();

</script>
```

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions and never marked any as correct? Theres a green tick next to all answers that you are meant to select to help others. Heres a helpful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `textContent` property instead of `text`, thus eliminating the need for `data-text`.
   Only several types of HTML elements support `text` property according to [HTML5 specification](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html): `<title>`, `<a>`, `<option>`, `<script>`, `<body>`.
2. Beware `document.querySelectorAll` result may not have `forEach` method in older browsers.
3. Use devtools (F12 key) debugger to inspect the values by setting a breakpoint inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To grab a value stored in a data-* property you need to access the dataset of the html element.

So your code would change from:

```
document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML += this.text;
```

To:

```
document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML += this.dataset.text;
```

Also, I would not use the data element as a selector--it is not their purpose --but rather a class element.

Your code is:

```
<button data-event data-text="Button 1">Button 1</button>
...
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-event]");
```

And should be:

```
<button class="className" data-text="Button 1">Button 1</button>
...
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
```

Final Consideration, try out JQuery, it will make your life easier and your code nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

The `text` property you're trying to access doesn't exist.  You simply need to change `this.text` to `this.getAttribute("data-text")`.